# how to invoke a web service in asp.net using SOAP

Tags: web-services, soap, asp.net-4.0

I have written a web service in asp.net 4.0. Now I need to invoke this web service using SOAP
protocol but not HTTP Post protocol.  Can any one suggest to me how can I achieve this?

Comment: SOAP always uses an HTTP POST. Why don't you want to use that?

Answer (score 1):

See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-MY/asmxandxml/thread/5486c18a-a796-4f70-9e56-ccee572abcaf.

You have to use Windows Communication Foundation

Answer (score 0):

See [How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/).